# Merging Identical Text Values + Summing

Tags: vb.net, vba, ms-access

I am looking for a way to Merge identical text values and sum them together to display a total.

So lets say there are 5 identical project numbers, each with time spent in normal numerical values like

```
PROJECT | TIME SPENT
451/676 | 4
451/676 | 0.5
451/676 | 5
451/676 | 4.5
451/676 | 3.2
```

How would I merge them to appear like

```
PROJECT | TIME SPENT
451/676 | 17.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the aggregate function `SUM()` and apply a `GROUP BY` to the project column:

```
select project, sum([Time Spent]) as TotalTimeSpent
from yourtable
group by project
```

Comment: Not really comprehending what I'm supposed to do. You are on about editing the VB code correct? In the Query? I've tried grouping and summing through the interface in reports with no joy. Adding that to my Query just gives me an error. 

SELECT [FTE data].Project, SUM([FTE data].[Total for project for day]) AS TotalTimeSpent
FROM [FTE data]
GROUP BY [[FTE data].Project,

I've shoved that in but there is errors in the group column (I don't know VBA)

Comment: @user2131612 Are you able to execute the query?

Comment: Actually, managed to get it working after fiddling with it :p thank you!